# How can I export user defined dictionarys in Libreoffice

Tags: libreoffice

How can I export user defined dictionaries in Libreoffice? I want to send a document to someone. The document has many user defined terms. I would like to send the user defined dictionary to that person. I do not know how to. I suspect that I can not, and am asking this question to hopefully have someone consider how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to export the dictionary explicitly. You can find the dictionary files in a subdirectory of your user directory (assuming you're using LibreOffice 3.X):

> /home/[yourUserName]/.config/libreoffice/3/user/wordbook/

You will find several `.dic` files there. The file `standard.dic` is the default dictionary, others are user-defined.